# Understanding Django Q - Dynamic

Tags: python, django, list-comprehension

I'm reading [this article](http://www.michelepasin.org/blog/2010/07/20/the-power-of-djangos-q-objects/) on dynamically generating Q objects. I understand (for the most part) Q objects but I'm not understanding how the author specifically is doing this example:

```
# string representation of our queries
>>> predicates = [('question__contains', 'dinner'), ('question__contains', 'meal')]

# create the list of Q objects and run the queries as above..
>>> q_list = [Q(x) for x in predicates]

>>> Poll.objects.filter(reduce(operator.or_, q_list))
[<Poll: what shall I make for dinner>, <Poll: what is your favourite meal?>]
```

What I specifically don't get is the list comprehension. A `Q` object is formatted with arbitrary keywords arguments as such `Q(question__contains='dinner')`.

If doing it like the author suggests with the list comprehension, won't that effectively just place a tuple inside a `Q` object on each iteration? Like such: `Q(('question__contains', 'dinner'))`.

I'm not sure how this code produces a correctly formatted `Q` object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The article relies on the undocumented feature that `Q()` accepts args as well as kwargs.

If you look at [source code for the `Q` class](https://github.com/django/django/blob/9c522d2ed8e752932bfff62d6e2940e56dee700b/django/db/models/query_utils.py#L53), you can see that it does the following in the `__init__` method.

```
class Q(tree.Node):
    ...
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Q, self).__init__(children=list(args) + list(kwargs.items()))
```

If you call `Q(question__contains=dinner)` then `args` in an empty tuple `()` and `kwargs` is a dictionary `{'question__contains': 'dinner'}`. In the `super()` call, the `children` variable is

```
children = list(args) + list(kwargs.items())
```

which evaluates to

```
children = list(()) + list(('question__contains', 'dinner'),)
```

which simplifies to

```
children = [('question__contains', 'dinner')]
```

Note that you could also get this result if you use `Q(('question__contains', 'dinner'))`. In this case, `args` is a tuple `(('question__contains', 'dinner'),)` and `kwargs` is an empty dictionary `{}`.

In the `super()` call, the `children` variable evaluates to

```
children = list((('question__contains', 'dinner'),)) + list([])
```

which simplifies to the same result as before,

```
children = [('question__contains', 'dinner')]
```

We have shown that `Q(question__contains=dinner)` is equivalent to `Q(('question__contains', 'dinner'))`, and therefore you can generate the list of `Q()` objects by looping over a list of 2-tuples in a list comprehension.

```
>>> predicates = [('question__contains', 'dinner'), ('question__contains', 'meal')]
>>> q_list = [Q(x) for x in predicates]
```

Personally, I might prefer to write

```
>>> predicates = [{'question__contains': 'dinner'},  {'question__contains': 'meal'}]
>>> q_list = [Q(**kwargs) for kwargs in predicates]
```

This way, you are not relying on the behaviour of the `__init__` method of the `Q`.

Comment: Absolutely awesome. Thanks so much for stepping through it.